# Mean values of a matrix in a matrix on Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, mean

This is about matlab.
Let's say I have a matrix like this

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15]‍
```

Now I want to know how to get a mean value of a small matrix in `A`.
Like a mean of the matrix located upper left side `[1,2;6,7]`

The only way I could think of is cut out the part I want to get a value from like this

```
X = A(1:2,:);
XY = X(:,1:2);
```

and mean the values column wise `Mcol = mean(XY);`.

and finally get a mean of the part by meaning `Mcol` row-wise.

```
Mrow = mean(Mcol,2);
```

I don't think this is a smart way to do this so it would be great if someone helps me make it smarter and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your procedure is correct. Some **small improvements** are:

- Get `XY` using indexing in a single step: `XY = A(1:2, 1:2)`
- Replace the two calls to `mean` by a single one on the **linearized** submatrix: `mean(XY(:))`.
- Avoid creating `XY`. In this case you can linearize using [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) as follows: `mean(reshape(A(1:2, 1:2), 1, []))`.

If you want to do this for **all overlapping submatrices**, [`im2col`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) from the Image Processing Toolbox may be handy:

```
submatrix_size = [2 2];
A_sub = im2col(A, submatrix_size);
```

gives

```
A_sub =
     1     6     2     7     3     8     4     9
     6    11     7    12     8    13     9    14
     2     7     3     8     4     9     5    10
     7    12     8    13     9    14    10    15
```

that is, each column is one of the submatrices linearized. So now you only need `mean(A_sub, 1)` to get the means of all submatrices.

Comment: I just ran the code you gave me and it got more than 10 times faster!! You saved so much of my time. Thank you very much.

Comment: @HigashiYutaka Glad I could help!

Comment: Computing the mean in all overlapping submatrices is easier: simply convolve with a 2x2 matrix with values 1/4.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good idea! I forgot about convolution

Comment: @LuisMendo: Convolution is my job... me seeing that as a solution is a professional bias. :)